# Synonym for something like "Relate Back"

Tags: word-request

> But this popular service, has also many drawbacks that the most significant one **relates back** to sentence translation.

---

> He is a very aggressive man. His behavior **returns back** to his awful childhood.

First, Do "relates back" or "returns back" make sense? I'm looking for a word like **dates back** which is common [as a help].

Comment: I was unable to grasp the meaning of the first sentence. ( Or otherwise prior/latter context provided. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your second sentence

> relates back

would be more appropriate since you may want to show a *relationship* between the present and the past

> His behavior *relates back* to his awful childhood.

would show his current "aggression" is due to his "awful childhood".

> returns back

might be used to described what caused him to "return" back to his childhood

> The events caused him to *return back* to his awful childhood.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is OK with some grammar adjustment:

> But this popular service *also has* many drawbacks; the most significant one **relates back** to sentence translation.

For the second example, you could say:

> He is a very aggressive man. His behavior **reflects** on his awful childhood.

See [*reflect*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/reflect):

> 6. *verb*
>      If an action or situation *reflects* in a particular way on someone or something, it gives people a good or bad impression of them.